# Strange Hex Number Encoding

Tags: c#, xml, hex

I am working with text readable files which are exported from a client's systems that use a custom XML-like structure.  I need to be able to parse and extract data from large numbers of these files with no documentation on how they are structured.

I have mostly worked out the file structure, however I am struggling with how values have been encoded.  I can manually look up in the system the correct values as a comparison.  Some examples:

```
Export Data = System Value

D411E848 = 500000

D40F86A = 100000

D41086A = 200000
```

I'm fairly sure the leading "D" is a token to say the field is a decimal or double value.  The reason is that all numeric fields start with "D" and all text fields start with "S".  The following "4" may also be part of the field data type, as all numeric fields seem to start with "D4".

However converting from Hex to Decimal on any combination of the export data value does not yield the correct result.

Any ideas how to do the conversion?

Extra data mappings:

```
Value   Export File
1   D3FF
2   D4
3   D4008
4   D401
5   D4014
6   D4018
7   D401C
8   D402
9   D4022
10  D4024
100 D4059
1000    D408F4
100000  D40F86A
500000  D411E848
500001  D411E8484
500002  D411E8488
500003  D411E848C
500004  D411E849
500005  D411E8494
500006  D411E8498
500007  D411E849C
500008  D411E84A
500009  D411E84A4
500010  D411E84A8
```

Comment: nothing obvious pops to mind ... did you try asking your client?

Comment: Do you have more data? Like 100001, 200001, 500001 ?

Comment: Client has a tool to read the extract files, but does not know the encoding logic.  For our current purpose we want to read the files directly, not via the tool.  I will edit the question to include more data examples.

Comment: This is in some ways related to factors of 4 it seems. Not quite obvious how though. Intriguing.

Comment: I edited your question to add some tags that may allow people more likely to have answers to find this question.

Comment: At first glance it doesn't seem to have any logic in it. Sometimes it jumps by 2, then by 4 or 8. It looks though like the trailing zero's are omitted, which make it hard(er) to find an exact conversion. If the client can't answer your questions, maybe you can try to decompile the current tool?

Comment: we have a winner: see the answer of @Caramiriel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a normal, but truncated, [IEEE 754 64-bit (double precision) number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format).

```
0x408F400000000000 = 1000
408F4 (truncated)
D408F4 (prefixed with D)


0x411E848000000000 = 500000
411E848 (truncated)
D411E848 (prefixed with D)
```

Try converting it with the following website as a reference: http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=053048048048048048

Comment: Well, well, to have overlooked something so obvious. Not such a big puzzle then after all. The fully deserved bounty goes to you my friend (in 15 hours when I am allowed to award it). If OP ever checks back on his question, he should mark this as the answer.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much!  I thought there had to be a simple and standard answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the pattern, starting from `2`. Here are the steps to get decimal value from your custom format.

1. Skip `D4` from the beginning of the string.
2. If `LEN() < 3` fill with `0`s to get at least 3 letters long string
3. Take 2 letters from the beginning of the string and convert using HEX to DEC converter
4. Add `1` to number get from point 3.
5. Get rest of the input string, skipping first 2 letters
6. Convert text from point 5. using HEX to DEC converter
7. Calculate `POW(16, LEN(Y))`, where `Y` is text from point 5.
8. Calculate `X / Y`, where `X` is number from point 6 and `Y` is text from point 7.
9. Calculate final result: `POW(2, X)*(1 + Y)`, where `X` comes from point 4. and `Y` comes from point 9.

It may looks quite complicated, but it's actually quite simple.

I've created Excel Web App spreadsheat with results for all these steps for your sample inputs: http://sdrv.ms/1bO0wnz

Comment: Kudos for solving the puzzle. As is clear now from the answer of @Caramiriel we seem to have overlooked the obvious. Nevertheless +1 for your solution.

Comment: Thanks for this illustration, it's very helpful.